# Asserting the text which changes with button click with css selector and javascript

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, automated-tests

I have to assert that with a particular button click the text changes.my javascript code is

```
.clickEl('[title="Smoke Blue / Chocolate"]')
.assert.elContainsText('.js-product-buying-table [data-id="actual_color"]',        'Smoke Blue / Chocolate');
```

the html for the text

```
</div>
<div class="js-product-variant-row product-variant-row" data-id="actual_color">
<label class="label-bold variant-label">
          Actual Color:             
<span class="js-variant-name variant-name">Smoke Blue / Chocolate</span>
<span class="js-unit-price-divider hide-content">
<i class="divider">|</i>
</span>
<span class="js-variant-unit-price variant-unit-price"/>
```

but when the test case ran the assertion fails with error
Selector '.js-variant-name.variant-name' was visible after 228 milliseconds.
Debugging information for elContainsText
actual text() result:[
      Choose an option]
 where "choose a option" was the default value..with html

```
<span class="js-variant-name variant-name">Choose an option</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to get at here with your question because it doesn't make much sense to me but this is what I could muster up for you.

I've just tried to re-do the code from what you've told me.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    addText();
});

function addText() {
    var colour = document.getElementsByClassName('js-variant-name')[0].innerHTML;
    var result = '';

    if (colour === 'Smoke Red / Rose') {
        result = 'Red';
    } else if (colour === 'Smoke Blue / Chocolate') {
        result = 'Blue';
    } else {
        result = 'Choose an option';
    }
    colour = result;
    }
```

Comment: I am using nighwatchjs for writing the test script ...... am trying to get the element by css selector and assert that it contains the text when a particular button is clicked ..when red colour button clicked it will display red ,blue button will display if no button is clicked it will display choose an option. but when i clicked red button and asserting the text it is giving false as it gives that the text is "choose an option" though the html shows there is the text red.